# Typical crawling depth by search engines

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler

When a site is crawled by a search engine (google, bing, etc), what is the typical maximum depth a search engine would crawl into a site. By depth, I mean number of hops from homepage.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the overall rank of your site, and the rank of incoming links, especially if they aren't pointing at your homepage.

Crawlers for smaller search engines like blekko aren't going to go that far away from landing-points of external links, unless your overall site is awesome or you have lots of links from awesome sites. We save our crawling and indexing energy for stuff with higher rank, so if our estimate is that a page will have poor rank, we won't bother.

Google's crawler might crawl quite a distance even if you only have a poor inlink profile - but even they know about 10x more URLs than they actually crawl.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crawl whole world then 19 depth is enough. Because whole world cover in 19 depth. But if you want to crawl for a specific domain or a country then 10 depth is quite enough.

I have found this info from a paper. Which was used for developing Mercator.

Thanks
Mohiul Alam Prince

Comment: The question asked, "how deep do the major search engines actually crawl?", not "how deep is it necessary to crawl to find all pages?"  That's an interesting claim that going 10 deep is needed; a link to the paper you mention would be helpful.